# How to send value to existing & overwrite in colum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

On the following code I have generated product name and than append them to list if length of title is less than 80. I want to add the out put overwrite the excel cell "Title". All function work fine till print(final_title) gives random title from all 4 format but when i am trying overwrite the data frame save to existing excel file. It give only

out put till print(final_title)

Solid 925 Sterling Silver Natural Ruby Earrings for Women Mother's Day Gift
Womens Rainbow Moonstone Earrings Sterling Silver 925 Gift For Her
Onyx Gemstone Handmade Jewelry 925 Solid Sterling Silver Drop/Dangle Earrings

output of df(print) is all 3 title of same format from the above 4 format for e.g.

Womens Ruby Earrings Sterling Silver 925 Gift For Her
Womens Rainbow Moonstone Earrings Sterling Silver 925 Gift For Her
Womens Onyx  Earrings Sterling Silver 925 Gift For Her

I want random format for each title not all the same format. attached is image to better explain.

I want to overwrite tilte colum excel and save excel

[Wrong : All title generated but all single format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVwH9.jpg)

[Correct : Output I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6AFe.jpg)

```
import pandas as pd
import random

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\example.xls')

for i in df.index:
    entry = df.loc[i]

    title_1 = entry['Main Stone'] + " Gemstone Handmade Jewelry 925 Solid Sterling Silver " + entry['Style'] + " Earrings"
    title_2 = "Womens " + entry['Main Stone'] + " Gemstone Earrings 925 Sterling Silver Earrings Gift For Her"
    title_3 = "Solid 925 Sterling Silver Natural " + entry['Main Stone'] + " Earrings for Women Mother's Day Gift"
    title_4 = "Womens " + entry['Main Stone'] + " Earrings Sterling Silver 925 Gift For Her"

    title_list = []

    if len(title_1) < 80:
        title_list.append(title_1)

    if len(title_2) < 80:
        title_list.append(title_2)

    if len(title_3) < 80:
        title_list.append(title_3)

    if len(title_4) < 80:
        title_list.append(title_4)

    final_title = random.choice(title_list)

    print (final_title)

    entry['Title'] = final_title

    df['Title'] = entry['Title']

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\example.xls')

for i in df.index:
    entry = df.loc[i]
    ...
    if len(title_4) < 80:
        title_list.append(title_4)  # Last line of the for loop

# Outside the for loop, assign the random value
df['Title'] = random.choice(title_list)

# Save to Excel
df.to_excel("output.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')
```